# Figure out which checkboxes have been selected in a form in php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a form with several checkboxes.  When I submit it to another php page, I am wondering: How can I tell which ones are checked without calling isset on every checkbox name?  (if there is a way).  If I give each of the checkboxes the same name, then only the last selected checkbox is returned.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quirk of PHP requires that form controls end their name with the characters `[]` in order for more than one of them to be recognised.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
   <title>Demo</title>

<form action="cb.php">
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="dog" id="dog"> 
    <label for="dog">dog</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="cat" id="cat"> 
    <label for="cat">cat</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="rabbit" id="rabbit"> 
    <label for="rabbit">rabbit</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="animals[]" value="hampster" id="hampster"> 
    <label for="hampster">hampster</label>
</div>
<div><input type="submit"></div>
</form>
<?php
if ($_GET['animals']) {
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($_GET['animals'] as $animal) {
?>
<li><?php print htmlspecialchars($animal); ?></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array name for all the checkboxes in the same group, e.g. name="mycheckboxes[]".
This way you will get an array containing the list of selected checkboxes in your php code